# Filtering items from Array of Dictinonary of Array in Swift

Tags: swift

I am getting a service response as below

```
[["realms": ({
        authorizationType = External;
        contentPageId = "<null>";
        description = "Demo accounts";
        externalRegistrationUrl = "<null>";
        id = 1;
        identifier = Demo;
        showDuringSignup = 1;
    }), "identifier": MENIISRE, "name": MegaTest, "imageData": < null > , "iconFilename": < null > , "imageDataId": 0, "id": 1, "orderIndex": 0, "altName": < null > ],
    ["realms": ({
        authorizationType = Internal;
        contentPageId = "<null>";
        description = Test Desc;
        externalRegistrationUrl = "<null>";
        id = 2;
        identifier = TestFB;
        showDuringSignup = 0;
    }), "identifier": 0012321, "name": TestAccount, "imageData": < null > , "iconFilename": a385bdff - 323 d - 4 a4b - 8019 - 233115 b43b38.png, "imageDataId": 1000019, "id": 2, "orderIndex": 0, "altName": < null > ]]
```

from the above response, I have to show only those record where '**showDuringSignup**' is 1.

One option is that I can run for loop on array & get the desired result but it is an old way & I want to use Higher-order functions (e.g. Filter, Map, flapMap etc)

Hence I tried with below code

```
let arrayOfAvailableBanks = arrayOfDictOfBankAccounts.map{$0["realms"].map{($0["showDuringSignup"] as? Int) == 1}}
```

but I am unable to get the desired input.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here and how to get only those objects where 'showDuringSignup' is 1.

Comment: Please show the JSON, not the array representation. From this output you cannot know if `showDuringSignup` is `String` or `Int`.

Comment: Can you please show the **JSON**? It's difficult to read the format you provided.

Comment: this  response not showing anything except confusion please show us JSON formatted.

Comment: Try using NSPredicate function, dataSource will be your json Array: -


let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF showDuringSignup %@", 1)
let searchDataSource = dataSource.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }

Answer (score 3):

You should use `filter` instead, Please find the code below,

```
let arrayOfAvailableBanks = realms.filter { (dict) -> Bool in
    return dict.contains(where: { (arg) -> Bool in
        if arg.key == "realms", let value = arg.value as? [String: Any] {
            if let internalValue = value["showDuringSignup"] as? Int, internalValue == 1 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    })
}
```

So the whole code would be like this

```
let realms = [["realms": [
    "authorizationType": "External",
    "contentPageId": nil,
    "description": "Demo accounts",
    "externalRegistrationUrl": "<null>",
    "id": 1,
    "identifier": "Demo",
    "showDuringSignup": 1],
                      "identifier": "MENIISRE", "name": "MegaTest", "imageData": nil , "iconFilename": nil , "imageDataId": 0, "id": 1, "orderIndex": 0, "altName": nil ],
                     ["realms": [
                        "authorizationType": "Internal",
                        "contentPageId": nil,
                        "description": "Test Desc",
                        "externalRegistrationUrl": nil,
                        "id": 2,
                        "identifier": "TestFB",
                        "showDuringSignup": 0],
                      "identifier": 0012321, "name": "TestAccount", "imageData": nil , "iconFilename": "a385bdff - 323 d - 4 a4b - 8019 - 233115 b43b38.png", "imageDataId": 1000019, "id": 2, "orderIndex": 0, "altName": nil ]]

let arrayOfAvailableBanks = realms.filter { (dict) -> Bool in
    return dict.contains(where: { (arg) -> Bool in
        if arg.key == "realms", let value = arg.value as? [String: Any] {
            if let internalValue = value["showDuringSignup"] as? Int, internalValue == 1 {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    })
}

print(arrayOfAvailableBanks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I may have decoded the response you provided.

The thing you need here is `filter`.

You can try this:

```
let array = // Your response here
let filtered = array.filter {
    if let realms = $0["realms"] as? [String : Any], 
    let showDuringSignUp = realms["showDuringSignup"] as? Int { // Change Int if necessary
        return showDuringSignUp == 1 // Change compared value as necessary
    }
    return false
}
```